Storybook v8 and Angular v18 render function type error (is not assignable to type 'ArgsStoryFn')
I have a set of stories for a component in Storybook 8.3.4 and Angular 18.2.6 that show a type error when the component includes an EventEmitter. For example:
class MyComponent {
  @Output() someEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(
    private readonly store: Store,
  ) {}
  // other properties and methods
}

And a simple story like:
export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<MyComponent>;

export const Basic: Story = {
  render: (args: MyComponent) => ({
    props: {
      ...args,
    },
  }),
  args: {},
};

Both in my IDE (VS Code) and when running in the browser I get a type error and can't run my stories. The error is seemingly unhelpful just stating that there is a type mismatch:

Type '(args: MyComponent) => { props: { someEvent: EventEmitter<...>;
}; }' is not assignable to type 'ArgsStoryFn<AngularRenderer,
TransformInputSignalType<TransformOutputSignalType<TransformEventType>>>'.
Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
Type 'TransformInputSignalType<TransformOutputSignalType<TransformEventType>>'
is missing the following properties from type 'MyComponent': store

If I remove any @Output EventEmitters the issue goes away, but as you can imagine I need those emitters for my component to work.
I stumbled upon a workaround whereby I change the StoryObj type to 'any' like this:
export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<any>;

export const Basic: Story = {
  render: (args: MyComponent) => ({
    props: {
      ...args,
    },
  }),
  args: {},
};

However, this doesn't seem right and I suspect I'm just doing something wrong.
